# trying to create a list with numbers from an infile to a outfile

Tags: python, list

```
def main():

    infileName = input("Insert To do list file: ")
    outfileName = input("Insert the new to do list: ")

    infile = open(infileName, "r")
    todolist = infile.readlines()

    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    for i in range(len(todolist)):
        print(todolist[i], file = outfile)

        infile.close()
        outfile.close()
    print("New list prints to",outfileName)

main()
```

I keep getting an error message saying `print(todolist[i], file = outfile) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Please help.

All I'm trying to do is take a todo list from a file that is listed as

> do hw
>   throw away trash
>   shower dog

and what I want is

```
1. do hw
2. throw away trash
3. shower dog
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation error:

```
for i in range(len(todolist)):
    print(todolist[i], file = outfile)

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Correct it like this:

```
for i in range(len(todolist)):
    print(todolist[i], file = outfile)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

And if you want to add numbers at the line beginnings, you should do this:

```
for i in range(len(todolist)):
        outfile.write("{0}. {1}".format(str(i), todolist[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lawrence has identified the issue with your code in his answer; you're closing the file inside the loop, which means the file is closed after you've written the first line. However, there is actually a better approach than having to close files manually.

Generally, when you open a resource that needs to be disposed of, you should use a `with` block:

```
with open(infileName, "r") as infile, open(outfileName, "w") as outfile:
    todolist = infile.readlines()

    for i in range(len(todolist)):
        print(todolist[i], file = outfile)

print("New list prints to",outfileName)
```

This way, the files are disposed of automatically once you are outside the with block.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to a closed file.  Inside your for loop you close the file with outfile.close

You can clean up your code a bit using the files context manager and python's enumerate function.  Here is a revamped version of your code:

```
def main():

    infileName = input("Insert To do list file: ")
    outfileName = input("Insert the new to do list: ")

    with open(infileName, 'r') as infile, \
            open(outfileName, 'w') as outfile:

        for i, line in enumerate(infile):
            print('{}. {}'.format(i, line.rstrip()) , file=outfile)

    print("New list prints to",outfileName)


main()
```

Using the context manager - "open(...) as infile" lets you forget about closing the file as python will close it once the context is out of scope.  Also notice that you can iterate over file objects.  When you do that, python returns the contents of the file one line at a time:

```
for line in open('somefile.txt'):
    print line
```

Another nifty trick is enumerate.  This function does:

> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator,
>   or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of
>   the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
>   count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
>   iterating over sequence.

Which is better understood with an example:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Finally, beware when printing lines.  Python returns the '\n' when it reads a line, so when you print a line read from a file, you will end up with an extra, generally unexpected blank linke.